# How many aldehydes and ketones can be formed from molecular formula C5H10O?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, structural-formula

**Question**:

> What are the possible aldehydes and ketones with molecular formula $\ce{C5H10O$ (including the stereoisomers)?

**Answer**: 5 aldehydes and 3 ketones

The degree of unsaturation of the compound is 1, so the ketone part is understandable since you take a carbon chain of length 5 and we have 3 possibilities for attaching double bond oxygen.

For the aldehyde part, I'm having trouble drawing the isomers.

Answer (score 2):

#### Aldehydes

| Structure | IUPAC Name | Common Name(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: pentanal structure] | Pentanal | Valeraldehyde, n-butyl aldehyde |
| [image: 3-methyl butanal structure] | 3-methylbutanal | Iso-butyl aldehyde, isovaleraldehyde |
| [image: pialaldehyde structure] | Pivalaldehyde | Neopentanal, tert-butyl aldehyde |
| [image: R 2 methyl butanal structure] | (R)-2-methylbutanal | R-sec-butyl aldehyde |
| [image: S 2 methyl butanal] | (S)-2-methylbutanal | S-sec-butyl aldehyde |

#### Ketones

| Structure | IUPAC Name | Common Name(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: pentane 2 one structure] | Pentane-2-one | Methyl n-propyl ketone, methyl propyl ketone |
| [image: pentane 3 one structure] | Pentane-3-one | Diethylketone (DEK), dimethyl acetone, metacetone |
| [image: 3 methyl butane 2 one structure] | 3-methylbutan-2-one | Iso-propyl methyl ketone, MIPK |